# Using array in MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to insert string values into my table through stored procedure,

I want to loop through this strings for a period of 4 months,

```
SET @values = 'test,foo,bar,user,';
SET START_DAY = UTC_DATE() - INTERVAL 4 MONTH;
SET END_DAY = UTC_DATE();
WHILE (START_DAY <= END_DAY) DO
{
......
insert into TEST_TABLE values(START_DAY,@values);
......
......
}
END WHILE
```

Any idea of how to go about doing the same ?